# Visual Studio Folders with Github

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

I have installed github a few days ago and just getting the hang of things, managed to figure out how to put my VSO source file into github repositories but since VSO makes an entire directory for each program full of other files along with the source file which go into the rep aswell. I'm not really sure if that's how it should be or not, But I would like for just the Source file to be sent into the repository.

Till now I've been adding with

```
git add .
```

I have tried the

```
git add <filename.cpp>
```

or

```
git add <filename>
```

but it didn't recognize it I think cuz the source file is within the directory that VSO made for it which is within my rep

Comment: What output do you get from the console when you type `git add filename.cpp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think i figured it out for now,I went one directory deeper and tried the `git add <filename>` again and it no longer shows the other uneccesary VSO files on my rep.ty